# Codeigniter GET ID with multiple page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I make a site with Codeigniter framework and I search to make multiple page with the same data in URL but I don't know how its call..

I have my user profile (`user/profile`) with an ID (`user/profile?id=2`) for example.
But I want, another page with the same information look like `user/profile?id=2/maps` for example, because `user/maps?id=2` was complicated an not logic..

How make this? How its call?

Another small question, how replace "2" by Username? like `user/handler` or `user/handler/maps`?

Answer (score 0):

You can make if simple function call in codeigniter with `User` controller and `profile()` function.For reference you can refer below code :

```
class User extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function profile($id=0,$page='')
{
    //do your logic here depending on the parameters above        
}
```

So you can simply call like this

```
http://your_base_url/user/profile/2
http://your_base_url/user/profile/2/map
```

Let me know in case of any queries.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer @Zeeshan.
Actually, my controllers look like this:

class User extends CI_Controller
{

```
public function profil()
{
    // Récupération de l'ID dans l'url
    $this->data['id'] = $this->input->get('id', TRUE);

    // Statistiques du profil
    $this->data['countReview'] = $this->review_model->countReview($this->data['id']);

    // Chargement du profil de l'utilisateur
    if (ctype_digit($this->data['id'])) {
        if ($this->user_model->getUser($this->data['id'])) {
            $this->data['users'] = $this->user_model->getUser($this->data['id']);
            $this->data['reviewsNext'] = $this->review_model->getReviewsByUser_Next($this->data['id']);
            $this->data['reviewsPrevious'] = $this->review_model->getReviewsByUser_Previous($this->data['id']);
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Utilisateur introuvable.');
            redirect(site_url());
        }
    } else {
        $this->data['error_report'][] = "Utilisateur introuvable.";
        redirect(site_url());
    }

    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $this->load->view('template/menu');
    $this->load->view('user/profil', $this->data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
}
```

And what is the $id=0,$page='' ?

THanks